# How to fix Python Gekko Max Equation Length error

Tags: python, gekko

My code work on small variables. But when I do in 128*128 array of variables, the error below is appearing:

> APM model error: string >       15000  characters  Consider breaking
>   up the line into multiple equations    The may also be due to only
>   using newline character CR    instead of CR LF (for Windows) or LF
>   (for MacOS/Linux)   To fix this problem, save APM file with
>   appropriate newline characters

I have no idea how to fix this error.

Assumption is the gekko just can't run the big array variable like that.

I put the code below.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO()
m.options.SOLVER=1
# optional solver settings with APOPT
m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations max', \
                    # minlp iterations with integer solution
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol max', \
                    # treat minlp as nlp
                    'minlp_as_nlp min', \
                    # nlp sub-problem max iterations
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 5000', \
                    # 1 = depth first, 2 = breadth first
                    'minlp_branch_method 1', \
                    # maximum deviation from whole number
                    'minlp_integer_tol 0.0005', \
                    # covergence tolerance
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.0001' ,\
                    'max_cpu_time 10min']

n = 128 
p = 8 
q = 16 


x = m.Array(m.Var,(n,n),integer=True)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        x[i,j].value = 1
        x[i,j].lower = 0
        x[i,j].upper = 1


s = 60

a = m.Array(m.Param,(x.shape[0],))
a_ = [172,282,10, 264, 287, 442, 393, 428, 484, 444, 344, 250, 293,  34, 473, 110, 338,  62,
 250, 205,  81, 336, 249, 199, 328, 447, 408,  82, 357, 334, 181, 133, 378,  79, 292, 103,
 494, 382,  10, 477, 237, 267, 337, 313, 395, 110, 114, 381,  52, 232, 457,  69, 167, 344,
 363, 284, 136 ,240, 258, 449, 119, 317, 370, 404, 197, 102, 428, 238, 321, 103, 282,  37,
  41,  86, 496  ,31, 148, 245,  78, 219,  37, 115, 378, 129,  37, 448, 415, 368, 238, 406,
 408, 100, 112 ,289 ,205, 329, 338, 396, 494, 145, 355,  45,   5, 220, 411, 167,  85, 369,
 426, 442, 406 ,217,  57, 176,  12, 368, 444, 227, 337,  63, 267, 216, 227, 182, 408, 116,
 385, 140]
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = a_[i]


O1 = np.array(range(n))
O_= np.transpose(np.nonzero(O1+1))

O = np.zeros((x.shape[0],x.shape[1]),dtype=int)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        O[i,O_[i]] = 1


d = m.Array(m.Param,(p,q))
for i in range(p):
    for j in range(q):
        d[i,j] = (round(p/2)-int(i/2))*4-(j%4)

#condition
m.Equation(m.sum(abs(x[:,:]-O[:,:]))<=2*s)

for i in range(n):
    m.Equation(m.sum(x[:,i])==1)

for i in range(n):
    m.Equation(m.sum(x[i,:])==1)

#Objective
m.Obj(np.sum(a.T*np.sum(x*d.reshape(1,n),axis=1)))

#Set global options
m.options.IMODE = 3

#Solve simulation
m.solve(disp=False,debug=True)
```

Comment: Have you tried using intermediates? These can help break down the internal equations so they do not hit this limit.

Comment: I don't try intermediates. But I have no equation can be represented as intermediates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a version that should work, if you let it solve long enough although a solution is unlikely because you have 128*128 = 16384 binary variables. There are 2^16384 solutions and a Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming solver such as APOPT is unlikely to find a solution quickly if the number of integer variables is greater than a few hundred. It can solve continuous variables with many thousands of variables but mixed integer is more difficult because it must solve them with a branch and bound method. You may want to try an MILP solver like CPLEX or Gurobi if you can make your problem linear (substitute slack variables for `abs` function).

Here are a few suggestions on your model:

- Do not use `numpy` for model expressions. Functions such as `np.abs` and `np.sum` do not provide the needed information for the solvers. You should use `m.abs2` (or `m.abs3`) and `m.sum` instead.
- The arrays `a` and `d` can be a numpy arrays of constants instead of Gekko parameters.
- You can break up at least one of your expressions into [Intermediates](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/Intermediates) to help with solution times.
- The objective function is a scalar result of `a.T x[:,:] d`. You can use multiple `m.Obj` functions from a[i] x[i,j] d[j] instead of one large expression that results from the matrix multiplication.
- I recommend that you start with a smaller problem and then scale-up to a larger problem as you gain confidence in the model and solution.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO()
m.options.SOLVER=1
# optional solver settings with APOPT
m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 1000', \
                    # minlp iterations with integer solution
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 100', \
                    # treat minlp as nlp
                    'minlp_as_nlp 1', \
                    # nlp sub-problem max iterations
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 5000', \
                    # 1 = depth first, 2 = breadth first
                    'minlp_branch_method 1', \
                    # maximum deviation from whole number
                    'minlp_integer_tol 0.0005', \
                    # covergence tolerance
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.0001']

n = 128 
p = 8 
q = 16 

x = m.Array(m.Var,(n,n),integer=True)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        x[i,j].value = 1
        x[i,j].lower = 0
        x[i,j].upper = 1


s = 60

# don't need a gekko array here, constants are okay
#a = m.Array(m.Param,(x.shape[0],))
a = np.array([172,282,10, 264, 287, 442, 393, 428, 484, 444, 344, 250, 293,  34, 473, 110, 338,  62,
 250, 205,  81, 336, 249, 199, 328, 447, 408,  82, 357, 334, 181, 133, 378,  79, 292, 103,
 494, 382,  10, 477, 237, 267, 337, 313, 395, 110, 114, 381,  52, 232, 457,  69, 167, 344,
 363, 284, 136 ,240, 258, 449, 119, 317, 370, 404, 197, 102, 428, 238, 321, 103, 282,  37,
  41,  86, 496  ,31, 148, 245,  78, 219,  37, 115, 378, 129,  37, 448, 415, 368, 238, 406,
 408, 100, 112 ,289 ,205, 329, 338, 396, 494, 145, 355,  45,   5, 220, 411, 167,  85, 369,
 426, 442, 406 ,217,  57, 176,  12, 368, 444, 227, 337,  63, 267, 216, 227, 182, 408, 116,
 385, 140])

# use .value to assign a value instead of over-writing the gekko variable
#   with a floating point number
#for i in range(len(a)):
#    a[i].value = a_[i]

O1 = np.array(range(n))
O_= np.transpose(np.nonzero(O1+1))

O = np.zeros((x.shape[0],x.shape[1]),dtype=int)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        O[i,O_[i]] = 1

d = np.empty((p,q)) # doesn't need to be a gekko array
for i in range(p):
    for j in range(q):
        d[i,j] = (round(p/2)-int(i/2))*4-(j%4)

#condition - use m.abs2 or m.abs3 for versions of ABS that
# have continuous first and second derivatives
xabs = [[m.Intermediate(m.abs3(x[i,j]-O[i,j])) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
# matrix summation
msum = m.sum([m.sum([xabs[i][j] for i in range(n)]) for j in range(n)])
m.Equation(msum<=2*s)

for i in range(n):
    m.Equation(m.sum(x[:,i])==1)

for i in range(n):
    m.Equation(m.sum(x[i,:])==1)

#Objective - can add multiple objectives
e = d.reshape(n)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        m.Obj(a[i]*x[i,j]*e[j])
#m.Obj(m.sum(a.T*m.sum(x*d.reshape(1,n))))

#Set global options
m.options.IMODE = 3

#Solve simulation
m.solve(disp=True,debug=True)
```

Comment: Oh my god,thank you sooooo much. Honestly, I'm a newbie in programming.It's really too hard for me. Please let me ask one more question, if I use CPLEX or Gurobi then I can get solution more fast? I try the code you write, but it run over than 10 mins . I'm afraid my boss will not accept that time.

Comment: Yes, Mixed Integer Linear Programming solvers with as CPLEX or Gurobi are much faster *IF* the problem is linear. Right now your problem isn't linear because of the absolute value function.

Comment: I don't know haw can I turn absolute  to other function.How about scipy if I use variable instead of array?

Comment: Scipy functions also don't work with Gekko variables. You have to use one of the Gekko versions of absolute value with `m.abs()`, `m.abs2()`, or `m.abs3()`. Each has a different approach.

Comment: Hi,I try to rewrite this code to CPLEX. I got a problem when I define the new variable z when @x[i,j]!=O[i,j] then z[i,j]=1 else z[i,j]=0.But it seems not work. Is there another way to use CPLEX? Or I have no other way to fix the absolute function?

Comment: CPLEX only allows quadratic or linear equations. An `if` statement won't work because it creates a function that is  not continuously differentiable. You'll need to use a binary variable for switching or the MPCC form (abs3 or abs2) in Gekko.