# How to know the maximum number of Equations when using GEKKO with an MINLP solver

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am working on an optimization problem and I am using gekko with an APOPT solver to solve it, sometimes and when I have a lot of variables, I get the following error "exception: @error: max equation length".
How could I know the "max equation length"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables and equations are written as a text file to the temporary folder before they are compiled into byte-code for efficient calculation of residuals, objective functions, sparse 1st derivatives, and sparse 2nd derivatives with automatic differentiation. Equations are limited to 15,000 characters each in `gekko` models, not just with the APOPT solver. This limit could be extended, but it is to encourage model building methods that improve compilation and solution speed. A simple `gekko` model demonstrates the issue with `x = sum(p)` as a vector of 10,000 values.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
p = m.Array(m.Param,10000,value=1)
x = m.Var(lb=0,integer=True)
m.Equation(x==sum(p))
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.open_folder()
m.solve()
```

This gives an error that the maximum equation length is exceeded.

```
Exception: @error: Max Equation Length
 Error with line number:  10008
```

The run folder is opened with `m.open_folder()`. The `gekko` model is in the file `gk_model0.apm` that is inspected with an text editor. There are a few ways to reduce the equation length for this problem.

1. The parameters `p` can be an ordinary `numpy` array, instead of `gekko` parameters. The summation is pre-computed before it is written to the model file.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
p = np.ones(10000)
x = m.Var(lb=0,integer=True)
m.Equation(x==sum(p))
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.open_folder()
m.solve()
```

This gives the following `gk_model0.apm` model:

```py
Model
Variables
    int_v1 = 0, >= 0
End Variables
Equations
    int_v1=10000.0
End Equations
End Model
```

2. If the parameters `p` need to be `gekko` parameters or variables, then use the `m.sum()` function instead of `sum()`. The use of `m.sum()` is more efficient than `sum()` or `np.sum()` for `gekko` optimization problems and avoids the problem with maximum equation length. The compilation time is longer than the first option.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
p = m.Array(m.Param,10000,value=1)
x = m.Var(lb=0,integer=True)
m.Equation(x==m.sum(p))
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()
```

3. Use `m.Intermediate()` when possible to reduce the equation size. This special type of [intermediate variable](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/Intermediates) incorporates model reduction principles where a quantity is explicitly calculated once and used in multiple places in the model. There are additional suggestions in questions / answers such as [How to fix Python Gekko Max Equation Length error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58853980/how-to-fix-python-gekko-max-equation-length-error)